# Is there a way to consistently prevent metro bundler from crashing?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, expo

I am attempting to write a simple react native application. I am using expo-cli as per the react-native documentation. After setting up my app directory, I run the expo start command on the command line as normal. However, metro bundler repeatedly fails with the following error:

```
Expo DevTools is running at http://localhost:19002
Opening DevTools in the browser... (press shift-d to disable)
Could not get status from Metro bundler. connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:19003
Connecting to Metro bundler failed.
Error: Connecting to Metro bundler failed.
    at _waitForRunningAsync (/@expo/xdl@57.9.24/src/Project.ts:1544:11)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:93:5)
    at startReactNativeServerAsync (/@expo/xdl@57.9.24/src/Project.ts:1873:3)
    at Object.startAsync (/@expo/xdl@57.9.24/src/Project.ts:2399:5)
    at action (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/expo-cli/src/commands/start.ts:181:3)
    at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/expo-cli/src/commands/start.ts:354:16
    at Command.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/expo-cli/src/exp.ts:80:7
```

I have attempted several potential solutions but to no avail as follows:

- I've tried removing the .expo file from the directory using the rm -rf command before launching.
- I've tried uninstalling and reinstalling expo-cli.
- I've tried running npm cache clean -f before running the expo start command.
- I've tried running expo start -c

None of these have worked for me. Is there any other method to try that I've been missing?